# Linked List causing random segmentation fault in M1 mac

Tags: c, macos, linked-list

I'm writing a text editor using ncurses recently. Everything works fine under wsl2 (Ubuntu). However, when I switch to m1 macbook pro, the linked list part causes Segmentation fault randomly. I don't know if it's because of the Operating system or not.
Here is my Linked List code:

```
struct character{
    int ch;
    struct character* next; //Singly linked list
};
```

And the part that is known failing is:

```
status add_char(struct character *head, int ch)
{
    if(!head)
        return false;
    struct character *curr = head, *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct character));
    if(!temp)
        return false;
    temp->ch = ch;
    while(curr->next){
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = temp;
    return true;
}
```

I have no idea what could be wrong, since the code runs perfectly on the Linux environment.
Please help.

Comment: Code is too incomplete. Questions seeking debugging help must provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to set `temp->next` to `0`

Comment: One obvious bug is that `temp->next = NULL` is missing.

Comment: This might be the issue. Linux seems to set pointers to NULL, but windows and macos won't. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Beginner mistakes.

Comment: A inked list of characters is the worst data structure possible. Just sayin'.

Comment: I'm just trying to use the data structure I know that's easy to insert and delete from the middle of the line without doing changes to the whole line.

Comment: You decide what you prefer, making changes to the whole line or blowing up your memory size 16x.

Comment: I'll re-write the editor using other data structures for practice later.